Moment of random variable with Regularly Varying tail; does this integral converge?
We learned that this integral converges, but I cannot show it myself and am skeptical.
Say $X$ is a random variable such that $X$ is non-negative and $X$ has regularly varying tail $RV(-p)$ for $p>0$. Then $P(X>x) = x^{-p}L(x)$, $L$ slowly varying.
Want to show that $L(x) = \left(\log(x)\right)^{-2}$ makes the $p$-th moment of X finite.
$$\mathbb{E}[X^p] = \int_0^{\infty} px^{p-1}P(X>x) dx = \int_0^{\infty} px^{p-1}x^{-p}(\log(x))^{-2} dx$$
I can simplify this integral using $$\frac{d}{dx} -(\log(x))^{-1} = x^{-1}(\log(x))^{-2}$$
In the following, I use the above substitution, combine $x^{p-1}x^{p}=x^{-1}$, and pull $p$ to the front:
$$p\int_0^{\infty} x^{-1}(\log(x))^{-2} dx = p\int_0^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx} -(\log(x))^{-1} dx = -p \left[ \frac{1}{\log(x)} \right]_{x=0}^{x=\infty}$$
But $log(0)$ is undefined, and $log(\infty)$ is $\infty$, so this just becomes $-p\left(\text{undefined}-\frac{1}{\infty}\right)=\text{undefined}$? I feel like I'm missing something or doing something wrong.
Can someone please help me understand why my professor says this moment is finite?
Follow-up question: If it does converge as written above, does this generalize for any $L(x) \sim \left(\log(x)\right)^{-\alpha}$ for $\alpha > 1$, given $X$ is non-negative with $RV(-p), p>0$?

The limit $\lim_{x\to 0+} P(X>x)\le 1$ is inconsistent with your choice of $L$.
Perhaps you intend $P(X>x)=x^{-p}L(x)$ only for large $x$, say $x>2$. Notice that  $X^p$ has finite expectation if and only if
$$
\int_2^\infty px^{p-1}P(X>x)\,dx<\infty,
$$
if and only if
$$
\int_2^\infty px^{p-1}x^{-p}L(x)\,dx<\infty.
$$
The choice $L(x)=(\log x)^{-2}$ results in
$$
\int_2^\infty px^{-1}(\log x)^{-2}\,dx=p\int_{\log 2}^\infty u^{-2}\,du={p\over\log 2}<\infty.
$$

Ahh yes, thank you!
